# Yii2 setter does not work

Tags: php, model, yii2, setter

i have a problem with yii2 setter, i have a field called "role" from another table, which the users and roles are linked with user_id  in the table "user_role", the getter works find, but the setter does not work, yii2 does not call the setter function!! , i tried too many things, i but the field "role" in the "rules"  function as safe, but it did not help, i wrote $role as public variable in user class, and i tried it as private but also does not work , i cannot figure out where is the mistake !!

```
class User extends BaseUser
{  
public $givenname;

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'user';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{

    return [
        [['role'], 'safe'],
    ];
}


public function getRole()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT item_name FROM "user_rules" WHERE user_id = :userId';
    $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);
    $command->bindValue(':userId', (int)$this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    return $command->queryScalar();
}

public function setRole($newRole)
{
die("SetRole has been called now " );
// Save role in the DB
         .................
}

/**
 * @return type array list of the system roles
 */
public static function getSystemRoles()
{
    return array(
        'sysadmin' => 'sysadmin',
        'admin' => 'admin',
        'editor' => 'editor',
        'member' => 'member',
        'register' => 'register'
    );
}
```

and in my controller here is the update action:

```
/**
 * Updates an existing User model.
 * @param  integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    Url::remember('', 'actions-redirect');
    $user = $this->findModel($id);
    $user->scenario = 'update';

    $this->performAjaxValidation($user);

    if ($user->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $user->save()) {
        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', Yii::t('user', 'Account details have been updated'));
        return $this->refresh();
    }

    return $this->render('_account', [
        'user'    => $user,
    ]);
}
//--------------------------
```

and in my view file:

```
<?= $form->field($user, 'role')->dropDownList(User::getSystemRoles(), ['class' => 'form-control col-sm-2']); ?>
```

do you have any idea ? could you please help me.

Regards
Wael

Answer (score 2):

The setter method will not be called by the load method, it just doen't work like that. The way you have your tables it seems like a many to many relationship, so you will need to do the following in your view:

```
<?= $form->field($user, 'role_id')->dropDownList(User::getSystemRoles(), ['class' => 'form-control col-sm-2']); ?>
```

And inside your model you should add the role_id attribute and set it as safe:

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public role_id = null;
    ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            [['role_id'], 'safe'],
            ...
```

Then in afterSave:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
    if($this->role_id !== null)
    {
        // Save role in the DB
    }
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}
```

And just to be through, so we get the correct role when using an update form, we do the following in afterFind:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    $this->role_id = $this->role;
    parent::afterFind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i did not actully solved my problem.. i figured out that i shoud overwirte the scenarios() function and edit the update ... so i add 

$newScenario = ['update'   => ['username', 'email', 'password' , 'userrole']];

Then i found that I should not user (Role)  name for my variable cause it's maybe reserved for Yii.

But thanks anyway for your help.